# adding boost filesystem.hpp doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost

I have the filesystem in my cmake:

```
find_package(Boost 1.63.0 COMPONENTS program_options system filesystem thread REQUIRED)
```

When I compile it says `Found the following Boost libraries` and `filesystem` is included.

Everything compiles fine. However once I try to include:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

I get the following error. What's happening here?

> ```
> CMakeFiles\runBasicBrimusTests.dir/objects.a(boost_filesystem_check.cpp.obj):
> In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
>  C:/Users/b.karjoo/Documents/boost_1_63_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221:
> undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
> C:/Users/b.karjoo/Documents/boost_1_63_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:
> undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
> C:/Users/b.karjoo/Documents/boost_1_63_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:
> undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> Brimus-Test\basic_tests\CMakeFiles\runBasicBrimusTests.dir\build.make:910:
> recipe for target 'Brimus-Test/basic_tests/runBasicBrimusTests.exe'
> failed CMakeFiles\Makefile2:293: recipe for target
> 'Brimus-Test/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicBrimusTests.dir/all'
> failed mingw32-make.exe[3]: ***
> [Brimus-Test/basic_tests/runBasicBrimusTests.exe] Error 1
> mingw32-make.exe[2]: ***
> [Brimus-Test/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicBrimusTests.dir/all] Error
> 2 mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
> [Brimus-Test/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicBrimusTests.dir/rule]
> Error 2 CMakeFiles\Makefile2:305: recipe for target
> 'Brimus-Test/basic_tests/CMakeFiles/runBasicBrimusTests.dir/rule'
> failed Makefile:169: recipe for target 'runBasicBrimusTests' failed
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [runBasicBrimusTests] Error 2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should add target link libraries in `cmake`.

```
find_package(Boost 1.63.0 COMPONENTS program_options system filesystem thread 
REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(mytarget 
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
)
```

Comment: Well I had linked using  'target_link_libraries(mytarget  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})'. I tried it your way and I still get same exact error.